# Breakdown current device

Tags: current

Is there any component that has a "breakdown current"? Similar to a Zener Diode but for current instead of voltage. It might function similar to a NOT gate and a fuse.

Comment: Do you mean a current limiter or constant current source?

Comment: @Jens ... What?

Comment: "for current instead of electricity"? How do a not gate and a fuse come into it?

Comment: did you mean to say `for current instead of voltage` ?

Comment: Are you looking for a PTC Resettable Fuse, aka PolyFuse?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called [current-limiting diode (CLD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-current_diode) and consist of a JFET and a resistor.

I wouldn't describe it as "*breakdown* current device", however; rather as "*shutdown* current device" because it must shut down in order to limit current.